# LaTex Error: No \title given for LaTex output by Lyx

Tags: lyx, titles

Recently I experience the Lyx error "No \title given for LaTex" when I am writing my manuscript with `\usepackage[OE]{express}`. I narrowed down the error is due to the automatically insertion of `\maketitle` by Lyx. I could not find any way to suppress the insertion of `\maketitle`. Is there a solution to it?

[image: Error message]

Thanks for [@scottkosty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12212/scottkosty)'s suggestion. I do agree that adding the sample code here is essential.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[OE]{express}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\title{-}
\author{-}

\maketitle % THIS LINE IS TO BE REMOVED, BUT I CANNOT

\address{-}
\begin{abstract}
-
\end{abstract}
\ocis{-}
\end{document}
```

In Lyx, there is no option to suppress the automatic insertion of `\maketitle`, which is the cause of the error.

> The package "express" could be downloaded from [OSA Author & Reviewer Resource Center](https://www.osapublishing.org/submit/templates/)

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question so that if others have the same problem they will see your solution! Next time, could you please provide a minimal example? Please see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @scottkosty took your advice and added an example. Thanks

Comment: great, thank you! Next time please add a .lyx minimal example. But don't spend the time for this question.

Answer (score 2):

After I searched online for a while, I found the solution by Jürgen in a mail list. In case the link [Re: Error message "LaTeX Error: no \title given"](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg51046.html) is no longer valid, I pasted the answer here (modified).

Two solutions:

1. quick and dirty:

   insert

   ```
   \renewcommand\maketitle{}
   ```

   to your Document->Settings->Latex preamble
2. Better (untested):
   in your layout file, insert

   ```
   Style Title
       InTitle               0
   End

   Style Author
       InTitle               0
   End

   Style Date
       InTitle              0
   End
   ```

   at the end.